# In batch file WITHOUT Admin Right, FOR command can't return output from ('command'), due to ERROR: xxx is not recognized as...command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm On **Windows 10.0.16299.125**.

Codes inside my Batch file:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('ver') do echo %%a
```

Output:

```
'ver' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I found if I run it without Administrator right, it comes with this error.
However, batch files always **run as Normal right** after I double-click it, even I'm logging as an Administrator account.

It works correctly before, but it just broke recently.

I have confirmed my Registry and Environment variables:

```
Reg: HKCR\batfile\shell\open\command: "%1" %*
Env: ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
```

**Is it normal that FOR command can't work properly without Admin right?**

I'm trying to restore cmd.exe by running `sfc.exe /scannow`. Thanks for any helping!!

---

**Edit:** I tried `sfc /scannow`. After finished, I checked **"%WinDir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log"**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>findstr "cmd.exe" %WinDir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log
2018-02-12 01:14:47, Info                  CSI    00000007 Hashes for file member [l:7]'cmd.exe' do not match.
2018-02-12 01:15:56, Info                  CBS    Repr: Add missing payload:amd64_microsoft-windows-commandprompt_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.16299.15_none_adf8f2af8b80fc99\cmd.exe
(p)     CSI Payload Corrupt     (Fixed) amd64_microsoft-windows-commandprompt_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.16299.15_none_adf8f2af8b80fc99\cmd.exe
2018-02-12 01:26:24, Info                  CSI    00001290 Hashes for file member [l:7]'cmd.exe' do not match.
2018-02-12 01:26:24, Info                  CSI    00001291 [SR] Repairing corrupted file \??\C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe from store
2018-02-12 01:36:47, Info                  CSI    000067ab Hashes for file member [l:7]'cmd.exe' do not match.
2018-02-12 01:36:47, Info                  CSI    000067ac [SR] Repairing corrupted file \??\C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe from store
```

### The log seems succeed repairing cmd.exe. However, when I tried again, `FOR` still failed...

Comment: No - it's not normal that FOR fails that way. I suppose that more than `ver` is broken on your system. Try other commands, like `echo` or `verify`.

Comment: @jeb Thank for your helping~! I have tried `echo`, `verify` and other internal commands, they all doesn't work...

Comment: Thanks for Helping. I figured it out. pls See Answer if you want~ Thx

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

My cmd.exe was broke by myself.
I used f2ko's software to **convert cmd.exe into Admin right** and replaced it.
I hoped I can run my scripts(.bat) with Admin right Automatically.

That's it caused this Error. **I restored the original backup of latest version of cmd.exe, now it works correctly**.

I'm gonna to find a properly solution to start batch files with admin right.